# How to change default help unavailable message

Tags: cocoa

When help viewer is not integrated within cocoa application it gives this message:

> Help isn't available for XYZ

Is there any way to change this default message?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could remove the standard menu item, and replace it by your own, that would trigger the action you want.